# java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception in browser

Tags: java, browser, applet

I made this little java code that runs notepad:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class pad {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        execute();
    }

    private static void execute() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
        exec.waitFor();
    }
}
```

The code works fine before and after building into a .jar file, however when running from an html page it gives me a java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception error, here is the html source:

```
<applet code="pad.class"
    archive="not.jar"
    width=400 height=400>
</applet>
```

Please note that I am still new to Java, thanks for your help.

Comment: Even if you got this to run as an applet, it still probably wouldn't work. Applets are generally untrusted sources of code, and I doubt Java's security manager would allow an untrusted source of code to execute anything with `Runtime.exec`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your code in a web browser, the `pad` class needs to extend `Applet` class (or if you use Swing - [`JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html)).

The first thing you need to know, is that applets are not started using the `main(String[])` method - they have a [lifecycle methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) like `init()`, `start()`, etc.

There is a good [tutorial on Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) on Oracle site, I strongly suggest you check it out.

Comment: so i changed it to "public class pad extends Applet" , it doesn't show the error anymore however it doesn't execute notepad either , what am i doing wrong ?
ps:i'll read the lesson now

Comment: For a start, invoke your `execute()` method in one of the applet's lifecycle methods, like `start() { execute(); }`. Also see @Jeffrey's comment - you need to sign your applet to run external programs.